# How to get slice data at the intersection of two surfaces in MatLab

Tags: matlab, slice, matlab-figure

I have flow data in a NxMxP array, and I would like to find the values of the data at the intersection of two surfaces. For now, I am working with a plane and a cylinder, but in the future I would like to use other shapes and find the data on the intersecting arc if this is possible.

Below is the picture of the plane and the cylinder, along with my code to make them. The red line is the intersection I would like to get the data on.

```
AR = 5;    R = 2.5;
Ny = 200;
% generate plane
[x, y] = meshgrid(-(AR+1):(AR+1)/Ny:0, ...
        -0.7344:(0.7031- -0.7344)/Ny:0.7031); % Generate x and y data
z = zeros(size(x, 1)); % Generate z data
% I needed to rotate the plane by an angle about y-axis for my purposes
V1 = [reshape(x,1,(Ny+1)^2);
    reshape(y,1,(Ny+1)^2);
    reshape(z,1,(Ny+1)^2)];
dphi = 7.5;    % angle to rotate in degrees
MR = [cosd(dphi) 0 -sind(dphi);...
    0 1 0;...
    sind(dphi) 0 cosd(dphi)];
% slice going through the center of the wing
VR1 = MR*V1;
xP = reshape(VR1(1,:),Ny+1,Ny+1);
yP = reshape(VR1(2,:),Ny+1,Ny+1);
zP = reshape(VR1(3,:),Ny+1,Ny+1);

% generate cylinder
Nt = floor(2.1*Ny*R);   % specify the number of nodes along the tangential axis
[Xc,Zc,Yc] = cylinder(R*ones(1,Ny),Nt);
% matrix for correcting the height of cylindrical slice
ty = -0.7344;
sy = 0.7031 - -0.7344;
Mt = [1 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 ty;   % vertical translation
    0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 1];
Ms = [1 0 0 0;
    0 sy 0 0;   % vertical stretching
    0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 1];
H = Mt*Ms*[ones(1,Ny);Yc(:,1)';ones(1,Ny);ones(1,Ny)];
Yc = repmat(H(2,1:Ny)',1,Nt+1);

% draw figure
figure
hold on
h1 = slice(Xw,Yw,Zw,ur,xP,yP,zP,'linear');
plane_sli = h1.CData;
set(plane_sli,'edgecolor','none')
h2 = slice(Xw,Yw,Zw,ur,Xc,Yc,Zc,'linear');
cyl_sli = h2.CData;
set(cyl_sli,'edgecolor','none')
axis equal
```

**Additional Work: Trying [inShape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.inshape.html#buia187-1)**
Following the instructions on the MathWorks website for inShape as suggested below.

```
shp = alphaShape(xP(:),yP(:),zP(:));
tf = inShape(shp,xC(:),yC(:),zC(:));
```

The `tf` variable is just an empty (`Nt`*`Ny`) x 1 array. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Two surfaces]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start: you can iterate on the plane (Xa,Ya,Za) and see where it intersects w/ the cylinder (Xb,Yb,Zb) using inShape; see https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/392798-finding-intersecting-points-of-two-3d-bodies.

In the future you could generalize this to iterate over cross sections of what the plane might be (a cuboid, e.g.), and then try using a binary search so you don't have to iterate through all cross sections.  Interesting question!

Comment: When I get a chance to try it I will. Please be patient.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it doesn't seem to work, I will update my question to show my work.

Comment: I tried running your code but it looks like the following variables are not defined: Xw,Yw,Zw,ur

Comment: Those are all data from my research, I cannot upload them because they are too large.